# Shared ArrayList between socket Java

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have 2 sockets: a client socket (Client class) and a concurrent server socket (ServerC Class) that can handle more clients at same time.
The thread server sends an array to the client when it connects.
If I update the array inside the thread server, then the program works correctly and the next client receives the updated array when it connects.
The trouble starts when the client updates the received array but if a new client connects to the server then the array is not the "new" one. That means that the objects aren't shared.
Is it normal? Is it possible to fix that?
Thank you and sorry for my english.

```
public class Person implements Serializable {   
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }

    public void setNome (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + age;
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socketClient = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1500);
            ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socketClient.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socketClient.getInputStream());
            ArrayList<Person> people = (ArrayList<Person>)inFromServer.readObject();
            for (Person p : people) {
                    System.out.println(p); //The second client will print Kevin too
            }
            people.add(new Person("John",54)); //This person won't be never printed for new clients
            socketClient.close();
            outToServer.close();
            inFromServer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
     }
}

public class ServerC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(new Person("Alex",21));
        ServerSocket socketServer = null;
        try {
                socketServer = new ServerSocket(1500);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int id=0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = socketServer.accept();
                id = id + 1;
                ClientServiceThread cst = new ClientServiceThread(socket,id, people);
                cst.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class ClientServiceThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private int id=-1;
    private ArrayList<Person> people;

    public ClientServiceThread (Socket socket, int id, ArrayList<Person> people) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.id=id;
            this.people = people;
    }

    public void run() {                 
        System.out.println(people);
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());                                                                                  

            outToClient.writeObject(people);
            people.add(new Person("Kevin",7));                            

            outToClient.close();
            inFromClient.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's normal. The client gets a copy of the array, and whatever happens to that copy has no impact on the server's copy. Imagine what would happen if any client would mess with the data on your server...